# krpano virtual tour asks credentials every changing scene in Linux Apache from iOS

Tags: ios, .htaccess, krpano

Centos 7 - Apache 2.4.
I have a subdomain which its public directory is password protected.
*.htaccess*:

```
AuthUserFile "/path-to-/.htpasswd"    
AuthType Basic     
AuthName "MMMMM"
require user a b c d   
Options +Indexes
```

User selects a directory to load a krpano virtual tour.
It works okay from some desktop browsers and from an old Android version.
But from iOS 13 (iPhone & iPad) in every change of scene it is asking me for username and password.
I'm not sure if this is the best site for this question, maybe it should be moved.

Comment: I’d start by checking what URLs actually trigger the authentication prompt.

Comment: krpano uses xml and JS. tour.xml (the main file) includes some subdirs content like `<include url="skin/vtourskin.xml"/>`